# WooCommerce Stripe payment gateway custom javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm having an issue with a JS conflict, caused by a custom jQuery script that alters text once the checkout has updated. When this script is included, the Stripe payment gateway on my WooCommerce site does not allow input into credit and debit card fields.

I'd still like the script to run, but have no idea how to resolve/avoid the conflict, so at the moment, I've had to omit it. Does anyone have an idea as to why the below is causing a conflict?

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() {
        var replaced = jQuery(".woocommerce-checkout #order_review .product-info .variation dd.variation-Extras p").html().replace('&nbsp;Booking Fee×1 ( <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>0.00</span> - One Time ) ,','Booking Fee (£0.00)');
        jQuery(".woocommerce-checkout #order_review .product-info .variation dd.variation-Extras p").html(replaced);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Some feed back on the answer below will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WooCommerce checkout, the element class `product-info` doesn't exist and the right element class is `product-name` instead.

Also you should always check that the html element object you are targeting exists and is not ***`undefined`***, before trying to use the `replace()` method on it.

So there is no javascript conflict, but **a jQuery error is thrown**, that disables some jQuery processes:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

and it disable all jQuery processes that are executed after it.

Use instead the following revisited code:

```js
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function() {
        var varExtrasObj     = $('.woocommerce-checkout #order_review .product-name .variation dd.variation-Extras p'),
            varExtrasObjHtml = varExtrasObj.html();

        if ( varExtrasObjHtml !== undefined ) {
            var stingToReplace   = '&nbsp;Booking Fee×1 ( <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>0.00</span> - One Time ) ,',
                stingReplacement = 'Booking Fee (£0.00)',
                theReplacement   = varExtrasObjHtml.replace( stingToReplace, stingReplacement );

            varExtrasObj.html(theReplacement);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It should work now without making trouble with Stripe payments.

Comment: Not my question, just voicing my agreement with your recommendations :) But, yea, totally onboard with marking answers as accepted. So many people miss that step :(

Comment: I am not the question asker. I just like your answer.

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, thanks for your reply. This fixed the issue to a point, thanks for your help.